# File archive issue

Tags: epub, epub3

I try to zip a file via CMD in the below folders and files.

```
META-INF -> Folder
OPS -> Folder
mimetype -> File without any extension
```

I have placed my cmd code for your reference.

7z a mimetype.epub

Please advise me, how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps it will be help for you
Step 1:

```
META-INF
OPS
mimetyp
```

This is the folder structure right.

step 2:
Select all one by one with order and right click the mouse button
Goto the send to --> compressed (zipped) folder

step 3:
Creating zip file the filname of `mimetype.zip`

step 4:
Rename the `mimetype.zip` to `mimetype.epub`